Xcodebuild test-without-build not executing single test case
I want to try with xctestrun file to execute test cases with selected testcases only.
here is my cli command,
xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun multi_test_config.xctestrun  -destination 'platform=iOS,id=XXXXXXXXXXXX' 

Output with 0 test executed and 0 failed, It has test cases.
Full sample,
xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun MultipleTestCases.xctestrun -destination 'platform=iOS,id=XXXXXXXXX' -only-testing:myapp-ios-mobileUITests/HomePageTests/testOnLoadHomePage()  
function> 

xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun MultipleTestCases.xctestrun -destination 'platform=iOS,id=00008101-00192C293ED0001E' -only-testing:'myapp-ios-mobileUITests/HomePageTests/testOnLoadHomePage()'
Command line invocation:
/Users/name/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun MultipleTestCases.xctestrun -destination platform=iOS,id=XXXXXXX "-only-testing:myapp-ios-mobileUITests/HomePageTests\/testOnLoadHomePage()"
User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Testing started
2024-12-06 19:56:59.583720+0530 myapp-ios-mobileUITests-Runner[1004:154035] [Default] Running tests...
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2024-12-06 19:57:00.050.
Test Suite 'myapp-ios-mobileUITests.xctest' started at 2024-12-06 19:57:00.051.
Test Suite 'myapp-ios-mobileUITests.xctest' passed at 2024-12-06 19:57:00.051.
     Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' passed at 2024-12-06 19:57:00.051.
     Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.002) seconds
2024-12-06 19:57:00.266 xcodebuild[93232:425450] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 2.896 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
2024-12-06 19:57:00.266 xcodebuild[93232:425450] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
2024-12-06 19:57:00.266 xcodebuild[93232:425450] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 2.896 sec, +2.896 sec -- end

Test session results, code coverage, and logs:
    /var/folders/dh/nwbttm2x76gfblk_yx3n5mrw0000gn/T/7D37BF20-8F52-462B-9747-C5014C730768/DerivedData/myapp-ios-mobile/Logs/Test/Test-myapp-ios-mobile-2024.12.06_19-56-56-+0530.xcresult

** TEST EXECUTE SUCCEEDED **

Any missing in execution please help.
